# How to trigger file download on URL without extension

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to trigger a download when the user clicks on a link.

The files hosted on servers I do not own/have no control over so I can't just add direct URLs to files (for example: `https://example.com/video.mp4`). I have tried the following code but it does not do what I want it to do.

```
<a href="https://example.com/filedownload?file=video" download>Download</a>
```

I expect the code to download the file when the user clicks the link. But when the user clicks the link, it opens a new tab at the URL instead of downloading the file.

Also, the link is not a MediaFire style download. If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> when on the page you get linked to it downloads `video.mp4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to trigger saving a URL to disk instead of following the default behaviour for the browser.

- The [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) only works for *same origin* URLs.
- A `Content-Disposition` header which requires you control the server hosting the file.
- Lying about the content type, ditto, and which is a terrible approach anyway.

The only way to achieve what you want would be to serve the file from a server you *do* control.

Comment: for a discussion about blocking `download` attribute for cross-origin URLs, see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/Iw3_SUcagGg/discussion